# Is it possible to apply normalization of input data via some layers?

Tags: keras, batch-normalization

I am building a Keras RNN model and preprocess my input to normalize (between 0 and 1).

I am wondering if there is a way to achieve the same through some first layer as a part of the model itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the model only has batch-wise information, it cannot do normalization with global max/min itself. However, if you can somehow pass your global max/min to the model, you might try this:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: (x-min) / (max-min))
```